# How to view html file in remote unix server?

Tags: html, unix, ssh

I currently have an html file on a remote unix server that I ssh to. I have been using SFTP to constantly transfer it to my local machine to view it after my edits, but I am tired of this.

What is the best program/method for Mac users to have a browser window view of the html file that is stored in a remote unix server? Or is there an ssh client that can easily edit html files?

Comment: If you simply need to view the file over a console session, I suggest links/lynx, which are text-based web browsers. Otherwise, as [Benny Hill said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21125276/1454048), just use a standard *nix editor.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is possible, but with some playing around on the server.

Once you have ssh'ed into the server, install a web server in that box.
Say the file is named *index.html*, you should make it available at the URL `http://localhost:8000/index.html`or port number can be anything.

The simplest method I can think of starting a web server at that location is

```
cd /directory/where/html/is/present
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000  # For python 2
python3 -m http.server 8000 # For python 3
```

This works provided python is installed on the server. It should not be that hard to install it as python is available from almost every package manager in every flavor of linux.

Now that html is available at python

`http://localhost:8000/index.html`

on that machine.

But we have not yet configured the browser in such way.

To do that you need to ssh into the server again, but with a -D option this time

```
ssh servername -D 7000
```

-D specifies application level tunneling when connecting via ssh

Then in Firefox, preferences/options -> Advanced -> Networks -> Connection Settings -> Choose Manual Proxy configuration

SOCKS HOST should be localhost , port no 7000.

Then the html should be directly available at

`http://localhost:8000/index.html`

in your Firefox browser.

This feature is only available in the Firefox browser.

Comment: Impressive. The only thing I had to change was the URL, the html was stored at 
http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: With python3, you need to use `python -m http.server 8000` instead

Comment: You can skip the proxy by doing a port forward e.g.
`ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 you@server`, this binds your local machine port 8000 to the remote port 8000.

Answer (score 6):

You can mount the remote directory with sshfs which gives you easy access to all the files.
E.g.:

```
sshfs user@server:/directoryToMount /localDirectory
```

Comment: Looked really promising but for brew installing on Mac: `Error: sshfs has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!` :(

Comment: I have no problems with mounting on a Mac (both Intel and M1) . To install MacFuse follow the two links in the first paragraph of  https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS . Be careful to install both, ssh and osxFuse.

To enable sshfs on your Mac go to:
System Preferences -> General tab -> Allow Extensions button
Then follow the instructions that pop up (make sure that you remember the instructions before shutting your computer down).