# How to view a html file in browser, when html file is on a remote server(linux)

Tags: html, unix

I Have a HTML report file on a remote server.I want to open this file on my local machine in any browser.

I tried the below steps :
--> Installed httpd on remote server,started it and tried to access the file using url: http://ip address of remote machine:8000/path to html file
This didn't worked.So I tried another way answered in below link
[How to view html file in remote unix server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124869/how-to-view-html-file-in-remote-unix-server)
Python is installed on my remote machine.
But this too is not working.
Can someone suggest the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly familiar with UNIX servers, but if you can install packages, try installing "apache2", then moving the html-file into /var/www/ or /var/www/html, depending on your system's and apache's version. In case you get a new version, the html folder is being created automatically!